# webpage layout distorts when opening website on a different computer?

Tags: css, web, html

basically when i opened my webpage on a different computer, my layout became distorted and some stuff went off the screen and you could not see it.

the PC i designed the website on had a larger screen than my laptop screen .

however when i zoomed out using the web browsers zoom function on my laptop, everything then went back to place again...why is this? how can i fix this?

how would i use media queries if that is the solution ?

below is the code: THANK YOU

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>The Sun</title>
         <style type="text/css">

            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                background-color: #91928C;
                font-family: 'Titillium Web', Calibri, sans-serif;
                background-image:url(starfield.jpg);
                background-size:cover;


            }
            .nav-section {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 20% 0;


            }

            nav ul {
                position: relative;
                left: 550px;
                bottom: 350px;

                width: 700px;

                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
                text-align: center;
                border-radius: 63px;
            }
            nav ul li {
                list-style: none;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 40px 60px;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 300;
                color: #323642;
                transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
            }
            nav ul li a:hover {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);


            }

            .container {


                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;



            }

            .info {
                position:relative;
                top: -1800px;
                left:550px;
                opacity:1;
                width:700px;
                color: #ffffff;
                }

            .content {
                position: relative;
                bottom: 690px;
                left: 500px;
                background-color:#000000;
                height:1200px;

                width: 800px;
                border: 3px solid white;
                opacity:0.8;



            }




            h1 {
            color:#FFFFFF
            }




        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="nav-section">
            <nav>
                <ul>

                     <li><a href="EarthProfile.html">Earth Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="EarthInfo.html">Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="EarthVideo.html">video</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>



        <div class="container">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="info">




          <center><img src = "earth.gif" height="800" width="700"></center>
          <br>
          <br>

          <hr> </hr>



          <br>
          <br> 

          <p></p>
        </div>  



        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, possibly including a screenshot or detailed description of exactly what "became distorted" means?

Also, welcome <3

Comment: basically by distortion i mean everything gets misplaced, all the divs get misplaced and its only after zooming out that you can see them again

Answer (score 0):

OKAYSO, to address your stated issue, you're getting different looks across platforms because of the way different browsers display various elements. To establish a solid baseline, use a [CSS Reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Take a look at what I've changed, this should be enough to get you headed down the right path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>The Sun</title>
         <style type="text/css">
            html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
            a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
            del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
            small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
            b, u, i, center,
            dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
            fieldset, form, label, legend,
            table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
            article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
            figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
            menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
            time, mark, audio, video {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                font-size: 100%;
                font: inherit;
                vertical-align: baseline;
            }
            /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
            article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
            footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
                display: block;
            }
            body {
                line-height: 1;
            }
            ol, ul {
                list-style: none;
            }
            blockquote, q {
                quotes: none;
            }
            blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
            q:before, q:after {
                content: '';
                content: none;
            }
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }

            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                background-color: #91928C;
                font-family: 'Titillium Web', Calibri, sans-serif;
                background-image: url(starfield.jpg);
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center center;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;


            }
            .nav-section {
                width: 100%;
            }

            nav ul {
                width: 70%;
                max-width: 700px;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
                text-align: center;
                border-radius: 63px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            nav ul li {
                list-style: none;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 40px 60px;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 300;
                color: #323642;
                transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
            }
            nav ul li a:hover {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);


            }

            .container {
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
            }

            .info {
                opacity: 1;
                width: 90%;
                margin: auto;
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .content {
                background-color: #000000;
                height: 1200px;
                width: 80%;
                margin: auto;
                max-width: 1000px;
                border: 3px solid white;
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

            h1 {
                color:#FFFFFF
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="nav-section">
            <nav>
                <ul>

                     <li><a href="EarthProfile.html">Earth Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="EarthInfo.html">Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="EarthVideo.html">video</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>



        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="info">
                    <img src = "earth.gif" />
                    <hr> </hr>
                    <p></p>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>



        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Your biggest issues were the use of "position" (read up on that!) and fixed dimensions. Use dimensions that are relative to the viewport or parent element going forward.

Good luck!

Comment: hi,thanks you so much for replying. i pasted in the code you gave me but there were still issues , for example the CSS info class was not in its proper place